# xcode. Converting strings with characters in HTML codes to Unicode strings

Tags: html, xcode, unicode, encoding

Here is the problem I have. Program on iPhone should synchronize with server, which also synchronizes with web version of service. Web-service sends special characters in strings to server in HTML codes (&#amp;, &#quote;, № etc.). I need to display this data, thats why I need convert this symbols to something, that xcode could decode and draw. 
As I'd discovered, codes in HTML end in Unicode are the same, differences are only in format (like № in HTML is \u8470 in Unicode). I'd tried just change this format in strings and encode it as UTF8. As result, now I have a function:

```
+(NSString *) replaceHTMLCodes:(NSString *)text{
NSLog(@"replacing HTML codes");
if (text){
    NSLog(@"%@", text);
    NSString *tmpString=[NSString stringWithString:text];
    tmpString = [text copy];
    NSString *tmpText = @"";
    int locAmp = [tmpString rangeOfString:@"&#"].location;
    NSString * Code = @"";
    int locComa;
    while (locAmp!=NSNotFound) {
        tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingString:[tmpString substringToIndex:locAmp]];
        tmpString = [tmpString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, locAmp) withString:@""];
        locComa = [tmpString rangeOfString:@";"].location;
        Code = [NSString stringWithString:[tmpString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, locComa)]];
        Code = [Code stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#" withString:@"\\u"];
        NSLog(@"%@", Code);
        tmpString = [tmpString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, locComa+1) withString:@""];
        tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingFormat:@"%C", Code];
        locAmp = [tmpString rangeOfString:@"&#"].location;
    }
    tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingString:tmpString];
    NSLog(@"%@", tmpText);
    return tmpText;
}
else
    return text;
}
```

But it doesn't work correct - it displays random Unicode symbols, instead of that I want. I'd tried to use NSUTF8StringEncoding, but it hadn't helped too.

Any ideas how to solve this? Am I right with converting codes?

Comment: This is a bit much to digest this early in the morning, but in principle I'd say run the data through HTML parser, which you set to output UTF-8 encoded text.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, Dave. Your answer were useful. Finally, here is my routine. Hope, it would be useful for somebody.

```
+(NSString *) replaceHTMLCodes:(NSString *)text{
if (text){
    NSString *tmpString=[NSString stringWithString:text];
    tmpString = [text copy];
    NSString *tmpText = @"";
    int locAmp = [tmpString rangeOfString:@"&"].location;
    NSString * Code = @"";
    int locComa;
    while (locAmp!=NSNotFound && locAmp!=-1) {
        tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingString:[tmpString substringToIndex:locAmp]];
        tmpString = [tmpString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, locAmp) withString:@""];
        locComa = [tmpString rangeOfString:@";"].location;
        Code = [NSString stringWithString:[tmpString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, locComa)]];
        Code = [Code stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@""];
        if ([Code characterAtIndex:0]=='#') {
            Code = [Code stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
            tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingFormat:@"%C", [Code intValue]];
        } else {
            if ([Code compare:@"amp"]==NSOrderedSame) {
                tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingString:@"&"];
            } else if ([Code compare:@"quot"]==NSOrderedSame) {
                tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingString:@"\""];   
            } else if ([Code compare:@"gt"]==NSOrderedSame) {
                tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingString:@">"];
            } else if ([Code compare:@"lt"]==NSOrderedSame) {
                tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingString:@"<"];
            } else if ([Code compare:@"laquo"]==NSOrderedSame) {
                tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingString:@"«"];
            } else if ([Code compare:@"raquo"]==NSOrderedSame) {
                tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingString:@"»"];
            }
        }
        tmpString = [tmpString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, locComa+1) withString:@""];
        locAmp = [tmpString rangeOfString:@"&"].location;
    }
    tmpText = [tmpText  stringByAppendingString:tmpString];
    return tmpText;
}
else
    return text;
}
```

Maybe, it's not ideal, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There was a small bug or two in your routine. This version seems to work...

```
NSString * replaceHTMLCodes(NSString *text)
{

    if (text){
        NSString *tmpString=[NSString stringWithString:text];
        tmpString = [text copy];
        NSString *tmpText = @"";
        int locAmp = [tmpString rangeOfString:@"&#"].location;
        NSString * Code = @"";
        int locComa;
        while (locAmp!=NSNotFound && locAmp != -1) {
            tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingString:[tmpString substringToIndex:locAmp]];
            tmpString = [tmpString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, locAmp) withString:@""];
            locComa = [tmpString rangeOfString:@";"].location;
            Code = [NSString stringWithString:[tmpString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, locComa)]];
            Code = [Code stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#" withString:@""];

            tmpString = [tmpString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, locComa+1) withString:@""];
            tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingFormat:@"%C", [Code intValue]];

            locAmp = [tmpString rangeOfString:@"&#"].location;
        }
        tmpText = [tmpText stringByAppendingString:tmpString];

        return tmpText;
    }
    else
        return text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Seems, I need to learn manuals more careful! It really works.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version. List of available codes could be found [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)
I created category for NSString:

```
@interface NSString (HTMLDecode)

- (NSString *)htmlfDecodedString;

@end

@implementation NSString (HTMLDecode)

- (NSString *)htmlfDecodedString{

    NSDictionary *codesToSymbols = @{@"&quot;" : @"\"",
                                     @"&amp;"  : @"&",
                                     @"&lt;"   : @"<",
                                     @"&gt;"   : @">",
                                     @"&euro;" : @"€",
                                     @"&laquo;" : @"«",
                                     @"&raquo;" : @"»"};

    NSMutableString *str = [self mutableCopy];

    [codesToSymbols enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString  *key, NSString  *value, BOOL *stop) {
        [str replaceOccurrencesOfString:key withString:value options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
    }];

    return str;
}

@end
```

How to use it?

As simple as that:

```
NSString *html =
@"<table>\
    <tbody>\
        <tr>\
            <td>Testing html symbols. Ampersand:&amp;. &laquo;Hello Double&raquo;. &lsquo;Hello single!&lsquo;\
            </td>\
        </tr>\
    </tbody>\
</table>";


NSString *result = [html htmlfDecodedString];

NSLog(@"converted html:\n%@",result);
```

It will produce html like this:

```
<table><tbody><tr><td>Testing html symbols. Ampersand:&. «Hello Double». 'Hello single!'</td></tr></tbody></table>
```